# AsyncTask doInBackground returns arraylist

Tags: android, web-services, arraylist, android-asynctask

I'm trying to get the json response from web service and put it into an arraylist. Then I want to get the arraylist into a recyclerview. I'm using asynctask to do it in background. The response of the web service is an json array.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String nombreChef;
    Double ratingChef;

    private RecyclerView rvMain;
    private RVMainAdapter mRVMainAdapter;

    private ArrayList<Chef> data= new ArrayList<>();

    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(Conexion.NAMESPACE, Conexion.METHOD_NAME_CHEFS_CERCA);
            soapObject.addProperty("idUser", Integer.valueOf(5));
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);
            HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(Conexion.URL);

            try {
                httpTransportSE.call(Conexion.SOAP_ACTION_TPNAME, envelope);
                String resultado = envelope.getResponse().toString();
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(resultado);
                 nombreChef=json.getString("nombre_chef");
                 ratingChef=json.getDouble("rating");

                 //IM NOT SURE HOW TO PUT THE ARRAY RESPONSE INTO ARRAYLIST????
                data.add(new Chef(12,nombreChef,"Riuos","21","Jr los belepos",12,"Delivery",ratingChef.toString(),"Activo"));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Estacion", e.getMessage());
                //result = "0";
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
        task.execute();

        rvMain = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_prueba);
        rvMain.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

        mRVMainAdapter = new RVMainAdapter(data);
        rvMain.setAdapter(mRVMainAdapter);

    }
```

This is the gson response from web service:

[image]

Comment: google "how do asynctasks work"

Comment: I dont get what you are trying to tell me

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: It would be better if you answered the question and if you do not know, do not answer anything. Do not waste your time or have nothing to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JOSN response either by using some library or by yourself using JSON classes that there in Android.
You can Google to get example for this.
an Example for doing it by yourself:

```
//Convert response string to JOSN array
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(responseText);
```

then you need to iterate over this array to get/extract respective data from it. Return this parsed data to get this parsed data in `onPostExecute`, from `onPostExecute` you can update your list adapter or do any update to UI.

You can refer [this](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: String responseText = envelope.getResponse().toString();
 then do parsing and add data to arraylist as you mentioned already and return this arraylist from doInBackground.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Chef>>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Chef> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<Chef> data= new ArrayList<>();
        SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(Conexion.NAMESPACE, Conexion.METHOD_NAME_CHEFS_CERCA);
        soapObject.addProperty("idUser", Integer.valueOf(5));
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(Conexion.URL);

        try {
            httpTransportSE.call(Conexion.SOAP_ACTION_TPNAME, envelope);
            String resultado = envelope.getResponse().toString();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(resultado);
             nombreChef=json.getString("nombre_chef");
             ratingChef=json.getDouble("rating");

             //IM NOT SURE HOW TO PUT THE ARRAY RESPONSE INTO ARRAYLIST????
            data.add(new Chef(12,nombreChef,"Riuos","21","Jr los belepos",12,"Delivery",ratingChef.toString(),"Activo"));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Estacion", e.getMessage());
            //result = "0";
        }

        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Chef> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)

     // your result.(ArrayList<Chef>)
    }
```

Once again check your json parsing.